# Does it matter if standardization makes the data negative in Principal Component Analysis?

Tags: pca, normalization, standardization

I am using this source to "standardize" my data: [LINK](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat505/node/55)

For this I have to carry out calculations of subtracting off the mean and dividing by the standard deviation. Does it matter if I get negative values in my data after subtracting the mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negative numbers aren't a problem for PCA.

In general, standardization will produce lots of negative numbers, because any value below the mean will be standardized to be negative.

Comment: > Can you/someone please recommend a source or formulae for normalizing eigenvectors/eigenvalues?